Wireopt variable in cadence virtuoso ADE simulator window
I am wondering about a variable in my simulator & output window in cadence virtuoso. It is wireopt. It is there by default when I start any simulation in ADE/ADE XL window. And the value is this. Can anyone explain me what is the purpose of the variable & the value.

